# authenticationManager.authenticate gives me error Required request body is missing

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, jwt

I was trying to use this function

```
Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
      new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()))
```

but gives me error

Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.acme.learningcenter.security.api.UsersController.authenticateUser(com.acme.learningcenter.security.domain.service.communication.AuthenticateRequest

This method is called in the controller. Please help me, I will be very grateful.

I hope this method works because it is part of this code:

CONTROLLER:

```
  @PostMapping("/auth/sign-in")
  public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody AuthenticateRequest request) {
    //if(request!=null) throw new RuntimeException("El request esta vacio");
    return userService.authenticate(request);
    //return ResponseEntity.ok(request);
  }
```

SERVICE:

```
@Override
  public ResponseEntity<?> authenticate(AuthenticateRequest request) {

      Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
      new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()));
      return ResponseEntity.ok(request);
      try {
      Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()));
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
      String token = handler.generateToken(authentication);
      UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
      List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
        .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
      AuthenticateResource resource = mapper.map(userDetails, AuthenticateResource.class);
      resource.setToken(token);
      resource.setRoles(roles);
      AuthenticateResponse response = new AuthenticateResponse(resource);
      return ResponseEntity.ok(response.getResource());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      AuthenticateResponse response = new AuthenticateResponse(
        String.format("An error occurred while authenticating: %s", e.getMessage()));
      return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response.getMessage());
    }
  }
I've been testing every part of the code and what gives error is 
  authenticationManager.authenticate(
      new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmcWC.png)

Comment: Could you please show the code of your ```AuthenticateRequest``` class?